# Connect to Project Server using the MS Project Object Model

Tags: project-server

I want to connect to project Server when I use the MS Project Object Model open a Project Professional 2007. Is there anyone do it before?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [Project Server 2007 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms455600.aspx).